# Throwable instance not thrown

Tags: java, exception

i read this code somewhere and when i wrote it in netbeans it is printing the desired output but a warning is shown "Throwable instance not thrown"

```
class Demo {

    public static void f1() throws MyException {
        throw new MyException; // Warning at this line i.e. Throwable instance not thrown
    }

    public static void f2() throws MyException {
        f1();
    }

    public static void f3() throws MyException {
        f2();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            f3();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in handled in main method");
        }
    }
}

class MyException extends Exception {

}
```

Can anyone tell me why it is showing this warning.

Comment: `throw new MyException();` You forgot the parenthesis.

Comment: ok thanks for replying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thanks QBrute for pointing out the mistake.

Correct Code

```
class Demo {

    public static void f1() throws MyException {
        throw new MyException(); // I forgot to add parenthesis.
    }

    public static void f2() throws MyException {
        f1();
    }

    public static void f3() throws MyException {
        f2();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            f3();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in handled in main method");
        }
    }
}

class MyException extends Exception {

}
```